# C#: which would be faster, how much, and why?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in a lot of my classes that usually just return a string from a list or dictionary. Check out the example below...

```
public string GetValueByKey(string key)
{
    if (!_configItems.TryGetValue(key, out string value))
    {
        Logger.Warn($"Key not found: {key}");
    }

    return value;
}

public int GetValueByKeyInt(string key)
{
    if (!_configItems.TryGetValue(key, out string value))
    {
        Logger.Warn($"Key not found: {key}");
    }

    return int.Parse(value);
}
```

What I want to know is would it be better to use the GetValueByKeyInt or would it be better to use the `GetValueByKey` and `int.Parse()` it at the spot you call the method?

Comment: what do you mean by "how much" ?

Comment: its not going to matter much if you first return then parse or parse just before returning

Comment: What I meant by that was, would it be a fair amount? If it was I would use the fastest, but if it wasn't that much I would use the int method for easy usage

Comment: Do you know the sentence "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"? This question is a perfect example for it.

Comment: Is this some kind of performance critical part of your system that it needs to be 'fast' ? If not then the usage considerations of clients calling this method is what's important - is it more convenient for callers to receive an int back ? If so return an int.

Comment: What did you already to measure performance?

Comment: read: http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: **Allways** use a profiler to identify how fast something runs and more important *where* (if any) you have performance-bottlenecks. Apart from this have a look at https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: (OT) Note that your GetValueByKeyInt will crash if the key was not found (value is null then)

Comment: Anyway which one is better depends on how you´re using the methods return-value. If you have to parse it anyway in client-code it doesn´t matter at all, as you have to do it anyway. But as you didn´t provide any context we can just guess.

Comment: For best performance in `_configItems` keep the value as the correct type and you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

`GetValueByKeyInt` will be slower, by definition. **Exactly** how much slower will depend on a lot of things. What version of the framework are you running? 32-bit or 64-bit? Which JITer? What OS? What processor? etc etc

Fundamentally, `GetValueByKeyInt` does more work (it calls int.Parse while the other code does not - and otherwise they are the same) - thus it must be slower. Also, when TryGetValue returns false, int.Parse will throw an exception (which is quite a big performance hit). *You likely want to use `TryParse` instead.*

But honestly, you should benchmark to see if it matters for your context. And it largely depends on whether what you want is an int, or a string. If you want an int, `GetValueByKeyInt` will be slower - but it will give you what you want (which is more important).